# Datepicker validation and AdornedElement.IsKeyboardFocused

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DatePicker on my form. When an invalid date is typed in by the user, the control gets a red border. However, I'd also like to display the error itself next to it.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFdc000c" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Grid>
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adorner" Margin="-1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="errorBorder" Background="#FFdc000c" Margin="8,0,0,0"
                            Opacity="0" CornerRadius="0"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            MinHeight="24" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=adorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
                                   Foreground="White" Margin="8,2,8,3" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <Binding ElementName="adorner" Path="AdornedElement.IsKeyboardFocused" />
                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="fadeInStoryboard">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.15"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="errorBorder"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="fadeInStoryboard"/>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="fadeOutStoryBoard">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="errorBorder"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    </Style>
```

In my `app.xaml`, I have this included:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/<assembly>.App;component/Styles/DatePicker.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

No validation text is shown next to the datepicker. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**
It appers this issue has to do with using `AdornedElement.IsKeyboardFocused` in the animation. If I remove the animation and set the Opacity to 1, the validation is displayed, but that's obviously not what I'm trying to achieve here. This code works however with the other controls like textboxes, checkboxes,..

Is there any alternative way to get this to work?

Comment: Why not simply use Validation.HasError instead of IsKeyboardFocused is there a reason behind using IsKeyboardFocussed. Like the snippet below:                                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                    <Binding ElementName="adorner" Path="AdornedElement.(Validation.HasError)" />
                                </DataTrigger.Binding>

Comment: Because I want to display the error only when the datepicker is focused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DatePicker is a control where IsKeyboardFocused does not populate property (Try WPF Inspector to check for yourself). Possibly because could be its not a typical input control and the Keyboard focus could be either at the calendar button or the actual textbox. 
The resolution is use to IsKeyboarFocusWithin.

```
<DataTrigger.Binding>
  <Binding ElementName="adorner" Path="AdornedElement.(DatePicker.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)" />
</DataTrigger.Binding>
```

Comment: You got to be kidding me... it took me hours to find a solution and it's so so easy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't say if this changed in some version of WPF, but the binding path `AdornedElement.IsKeyboardFocusWithin` worked for me and then you don't need a special error template for a DatePicker (this works for all controls I've tested).

Comment: Works for numericupdown control as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use a popup for you're template and you can use the placement property to position it around your control.

```
<Popup x:Name="Popup"
               Placement="Right"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=adorner}">
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="{DynamicResource UI.ErrorBrush}" Padding="5 4">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent,
                                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                                 AncestorType={x:Type Adorner}},
                                                  FallbackValue=null, Mode=OneTime}"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

To add behaviour to your popup you need to apply data triggers to do what you want when you want it.

include this at the top

```
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

and within the popup create your triggers

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
<!--  Shows Popup when TextBox has focus  -->
<ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.IsFocused, FallbackValue=False}" Value="True">
    <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="IsOpen"
                                         TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Popup,
                                                                FallbackValue=null}"
                                         Value="True" />
    <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.IsFocused, FallbackValue=False}" Value="False">
        <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="IsOpen"
                                         TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Popup,
                                                                FallbackValue=null}"
                                         Value="False" />
    </ei:DataTrigger>
```

you will also want triggers to hide the popup when the errors are null because if it has an animation (fade for instance) the text in the popup will display null as it fades away. this can just be a single trigger on the error count equalling 0 and setting animation to none/hiding.

Comment: try using those databindings they should work, if not it'll be something very similar. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm, I think something is wrong with that logic:
Error 10 A value of type 'DataTrigger' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'TriggerCollection'.